# Only option available from team eclipse is synchronize workspace and apply patch

Tags: java, eclipse, github, share

I want to share my project to github but the onloy options im getting are synchronize workspace and apply patch. I have all my other projects working just fine sharen in github.

[image]

As i press them, they do nothing, i just want to share my project in github.

Comment: The right-click menu is context-sensitive. In which view did you right-click on what? Please tell also your Eclipse version. Do you get the same menu also for a new project?

Comment: The option to "Add to CodeTogether Ignore" is shown--is this project already under a different SCM?